# Flat Screen Monitor No Sound

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, display, speakers

[image: Device Manager]

I have a Lenovo Thinkcentre M91P Minitower PC, HP 2448hc flatscreen monitor and GTX750Ti Graphics card. Windows 10.

The monitor has built in speakers. Recently, the sound seemed really tinny and quiet after booting up (with everything set to 100). I think there had been a Windows 10 update. Then I realised, the sound was coming from the little inbuilt speaker in the computer itself. I cannot make sound come from the bigger speaker in the flatscreen monitor anymore.

When I click on "manage sound devices" in control panel, it just says "Speakers: Realtek HD Audio (Default Device)". When I select "test", the sound comes out of the computer tower again - and not the flatscreen speaker like it always used to.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? I have no idea what is going on. It seems to be as if the speaker in my flatscreen monitor doesn't exist anymore.

BTW: I updated drivers in Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio), HP w2448h Wide LCD Monitor and in Sound Video and Game Controllers. It always said "best driver already installed". So that's no help.

Comment: Right-click in the Playback tab of the "Manage Audio Devices" window. Are "Show disabled/disconnected devices" both checked?

Comment: Yes. It still only shows Speakers: Realtek High Definition Audio.

Comment: How is the monitor connected to your computer? Do the builtin speakers have their own connection?

Comment: It's Connected via HDMI (monitor end) to DVI (PC end).

Comment: Okay, well that *technically* could work, as long as your cable is the correct type (DVI-D). You graphics card should have an HDMI port, can you try using that as a test?

Comment: @MichaelFrank HDMI test is a good idea but OP implies that it used to work fine...can you confirm that Maidenhair? If so, have you made any changes before it stopped working, aside from the Windows Update that you suspect?

Comment: It always has worked until now - that's what's odd. OK, I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: The only other change was NVIDIA control panel which I think updated.

Comment: Now I have HDMI connection on the PC (Graphics Card) end and DVI on the monitor end. Situation with sound is unchanged.

Comment: I think you'd have to try HDMI to HDMI...

Comment: DVI on the monitor will probably not pick up audio at all. It only works the other way around (afaik).

Comment: I've given up so I bought USB speakers for £8 on Amazon.

Comment: @Maidenhair Last question then I guess... Have you checked in the NVidia control panel for audio options? It could be that the update you mentioned turned off the audio output for HDMI.

Comment: I think that was still there (i.e. the same as it always was). Anyway speakers are working nicely so I'll probs just use those. Thanks anyway :)